# Cannot track the user securely who made the purchase in PayPal IPN

Tags: security, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am building a website which utilizes paypal payment system and I came up with one security challenge issue:

I have the following form from paypal IPN:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABCDEFEGDEDS">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Balance">
<label>Amount</label>
    <select class="form-control"  name="os0" id="deposit_paypal">
        <option value="1000">$1000.00 USD</option>
        <option value="2000">$2000.00 USD</option>
    </select>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/ru_RU/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

I wanted to know which user has made the transaction. Searching the internet, I've found that I can create a custom field as I did above.  The reason I track the user is I should add balance to his virtual account after purchase completed.

1. But the problem is: What if malicious code(javascript malware) just changes the user id in the custome form field to 4?
   The balance will be added to that user which has the id of 4 not previous one.
2. Ok. One would recommend me inserting the form data to db before sending to paypal for later comparison. 
   Second problem arises. What if the user just exits the paypal page without completing the order after pressing the submit button? This is something I cannot track since paypal does not belong to me and it opens in other page.

Please, any other solution to these issues? I want some best practice where I can track securely which user has made the purchase through paypal IPN.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in your database within a temp table, then once the IPN completes you can move it over to the permanent table.  Set up a cron job or scheduled task to go through your system every 24 hours or so and delete any records that have not completed in that time.

Comment: I think this has also some security issues, @PP_MTS_Chad. Let's say a malicious code changes the A person's id from 1 to 4 and you wrote it to temp table. But A person did not complete the transaction and quit. However, you have it in your temp folder. Second B person within 24 hours did complete his transaction. In this case malware also changed his id from 2 to 4. The money will transfer to the person who has id of 4. Therefore, there must me other solution..but I cannot find it..

Comment: You could create hosted buttons or encrypted on the fly so that the specific data could not be changed.